# what does it mean by lucid and karmic users?

Tags: users, unknown-device

please feed some info on both of these. I want to both the diffence and how to diffrentiate amongst lucid and karmic user and which category do i fall into?

Comment: Both are no longer supported Ubuntu releases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every Ubuntu release gets its own codename. For instance, Ubuntu 15.04 is called Vivid Vervet. 14.04 is called Trusty Tahr. Lucid and Karmic aren't "categories," they're version names of two different releases of Ubuntu.

Lucid's full name is Lucid Lynx. It's the codename for Ubuntu 10.04, which was released in April of 2010. It's really old, and no longer supported, so you shouldn't install it.

Karmic's full name is Karmic Koala: Ubuntu 9.10. It's even older than Lucid. Please don't attempt to install this version either.

You don't fit into either category, because they aren't categories. They're consecutive releases of Ubuntu. I'm a little unsure as to what made you think they were categories of any sort.

If you want to install Ubuntu, you need to download one of the newer versions, such as Trusty Tahr (14.04 LTS) or Wily Werewolf (15.10). 14.04 is LTS, meaning "Long-Term Support." Releases like this happen every two years, so the next one, 16.04, is going to be released this April. LTS releases, like the name suggests, are kept under support for a very long time. 14.04, for instance, is supported until 2019, I believe. If you don't trust yourself with frequent upgrades to newer versions of Ubuntu, stay with LTS. You won't get any version of Ubuntu that has a short support term, like 15.04, which is going ot reach its End-of-Life on February 4th.

Ubuntu also has a system for releases. 10.04 was released in April 2010. 11.04 was released in April 2011. 10.10 was released in October 2010. 11.10 was released in October 2011. See a pattern? The first number in the version is the year, and the second number is the month: yy.mm.

If you are thinking of installing Ubuntu, go to the [Ubuntu website](http://ubuntu.com) and download 14.04 LTS. If you have Windows, use [Rufus](http://rufus.akeo.ie) to burn the ISO to a USB drive, and then boot from that drive. If you have a Mac, you'll have to use UNETBootin to burn the ISO to a USB drive.

Any clarifications? Comment.

Answer (score 0):

They're respectively users of Ubuntu Lucid Lynx (thatis, Ubuntu 10.04 LTS) and Ubuntu Karmic Koala (thatis, Ubuntu 9.10).

[You can have a look at the list of Ubuntu releases here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Ubuntu_releases).

To know which version you are running, type the following in a terminal:

```
lsb_release -a
```